# Common Listener for a bunch of radio groups

Tags: android, listener, radio-group

I have about 60 radio groups that I need to register a listener for. Currently this is how I do it:

```
    RadioGroup rg1 = (RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.rdoGrp1);
    rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    rg1 = (RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.rdoGrp2);
    rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    rg1 = (RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.rdoGrp3);
    rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

and so on for the 60 radio groups. Is there a way to set all radio groups on the fragment to register to a common listener in a single statement or two without having to type out this much code? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the RadioGroup elements share the same parent, you could iterate using [ViewGroup.getChildAt](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29) and [ViewGroup.getChildCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildCount%28%29). Something like this:

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.ParentViewId);
for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View currentView = parent.getChildAt(i);
    if (currentView instanceof RadioGroup) {
        ((RadioGroup) currentView).setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Great idea! I will try to get a create a common parent for all the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to create a method in your activity or whatever class you are writing, something like this:

```
private void registerListenerToGroup(int groupId) {
    RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(groupId);
    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
}
```

Then, call this method from your code like this:

```
registerListenerToGroup(R.id.rdoGrp1);
registerListenerToGroup(R.id.rdoGrp2);
registerListenerToGroup(R.id.rdoGrp3);
//etc.
```